# Como num listener, atribuído a mais de um Spinner, saber quem o chamou?

Tags: java, android

Eu estou usando 4 spinners em uma única activity e preciso receber a informação de cada Spinner. A questão é que pra usar o Spinner é usado o método "onItemSelected", e deve atribuir o valor de uma variável a "`parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();`".

A questão é que eu tô usando 4 spinners dentro desse mesmo método, e preciso atribuir o "`parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();`" em 4 variáveis diferentes, porém, tá atribuindo o mesmo spinner às 4 variáveis.

Como faço pra diferenciar os spinners sendo que estão sendo usadas no mesmo método?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, é sempre melhor colocar o código que você chegou a fazer, ou pelo menos uma representação, se não for possível colocar o código original.

De qualquer forma, vou assumir que você está implementando a interface OnSelectedItemListener na sua Activity e passando essa instância para seus Spinners:

```
public class MainActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

(...)

spinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Acontece que, dessa forma, você só tem um listener para 4 Spinners, quando na verdade você precisa de 4 listeners.

Uma forma de implementar esses 4 listeners seria:

```
spinner1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // tratar cliques do Spinner 1
    }
});

spinner2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // tratar cliques do Spinner 2
    }
});

spinner3.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // tratar cliques do Spinner 3
    }
});

spinner4.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // tratar cliques do Spinner 4
    }
});
```

Comment: Eu tinha feito isso mesmo e funcionou, esse era o problema. 
Valeu amigo! :)

Answer (score 1):

O método `onItemSelected` recebe, no parâmetro *parent*, o *Spinner* cujo item foi seleccionado.

Para saber qual é esse *Spinner* basta verificar o seu **id** .

Qualquer coisa assim:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int pos, long id) {
    if(parent.getId() == R.id.spinner1){
        variavel1 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }
    else if(parent.getId() == R.id.spinner2){
        variavel2 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Eventualmente, por uma questão de organização, manutenção e/ou melhor legibilidade, poderá ser preferível ter um *listener* por cada um dos *Spinner*.